# Is gud working at all in emacs 24?

Tags: gud

I am trying to switch from vim to evil mode and got very far. The last thing what is missing is debugging with "gdb". I want to be equally productive as with clewn in vim (this means source level debugging, not a bare command line interface). So I tried with gud-many-windows.

But with gud I experience lots of issues, which make it totally unusable for me. The most prominent is, that gud doesn't seem to follow jumps in other functions or other files. So if I step into function, the white indicator simply goes away. Manually invoking gud-refresh sometimes helps. But sometimes, the source also pops up in some other window then (e.g. the *input/output* window) or not at all. So I have to go some steps "in the dark" before gud-refresh helps again.

There are many people in the web experiencing similar problems, but there doesn't seem to be any solution (at least none, I could understand so far). In some forums it is stated, that debugging in emacs 24 is broken and I should go back to 23.

Another issue seems to be that it is totally unconfigurable. So making the *input/output* window disapear meant to literally copy 50 lines from the gud sources and modify them via defadvice ... What the heck?

I also tried realgud, but was not even able to invoke gdb with it. On 25.0.50 I had the same problems then with 24.

Best regards,
Kilian.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x gud-gdb` is fine when debugging on emacs24, this works on gdb6+

`M-x gdb` requires gdb7+

when debugging, you need compile your program with `gcc -g -O0`. I use `M-x gud-gdb` on both Mac/Linux without issue.

Comment: Yeah, gud-gdb might work. But not gud-many-windows via M-x gdb, as I described above. In fact, in every forum the people say, use: gud-gdb. But this has a much more spartanic interface though. As I got realgud working in the meantime, I will try to use that.